# How to insert into and update sql using NodeJS, socket.io, postgres correctly?

Tags: node.js, socket.io, postgresql-9.1, postgresql-9.3, pg

I'm a baby in programming especially NodeJS and Javascript. I've been learning about how to connect to PostgreSQL via Javascript using NodeJS and socket.io.

I have searched and found this link http://gonzalo123.com/2012/05/07/asynchronous-queries-to-relational-databases-from-browser-with-node-js-and-socket-io/. Followed him and works well with select and update statement.

However, I still can't accomplish with insert into statement and update with specified values. Here is my current code.

**Server Side:**

```
var pg = require('pg');

var conString = "tcp://postgres:1234@localhost:5432/testdb";
var client = new pg.Client(conString);
client.connect();

var io = require('socket.io').listen(8888);

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
socket.on('sql', function (data) {
var query = client.query(data.sql, data.values);
query.on('row', function(row) {
socket.emit('sql', row);
});
});
});
```

**Client (html):**

```
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
 <script src="http://localhost:8888/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
 <script>
 var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8888');
 var mobileno = '0123456789';
 function sendSql(sql, values, cbk) {
socket.emit('sql', { sql: sql, values : values});
socket.on('sql', function(data){
    console.log(data);
});
}

</script>    
<p>
 <a href="#" onclick="sendSql('select * from user', [], function(data)          {console.log(data);})">Select</a>
 </p>

 <a href="#" onclick="sendSql('UPDATE user set mobile = 987654321 where id=12 ', [],  function(data) {})">Update</a>
 </p>
 <p>
   <a href="#" onclick="sendSql('INSERT INTO user (name) values('Michael'),[], function(data)    {console.log(data);})">Insert</a>
 </p>


 </body>
 </html>
```

From above code, Select statement works perfectly with all data shows in Chrome's console.

For Update Statement, I can update data in column 'mobile' with value '987654321'. But what I want is 
the value from `var mobileno = '123456789';` then I tried...

```
UPDATE user set mobile = mobileno
```

It doesn't works and the console of server says "column mobileno doesn't exists".

For Insert Statement, I really have no idea with this. Tried to change syntax many ways but still can't make it works and still get various errors.

I guess somebody here should have experience with this. Please kindly teach me how to use update and insert into statement of this thing correctly.

Comment: This is without a doubt, the most unsafe implementation of SQL I've ever seen.

Answer (score 1):

Ok. I just solved this. After searched for more information about this, i found that i must use

```
UPDATE user set mobile = '+mobileno+'
```

to make it works. It's all about syntax. Now i can do query statements myself. Thank you.